# Change Color For Parts of an Image

Tags: c#, colors, gdi+

I am trying find a solution that would allow me change color for parts of an image.

For example lets say a picture of a chair. 
A chair can have different frame or cushion colors.
I intend to let users select a frame or cushion and update the image.
We can only upload one chair image.

Any idea is much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you could build the image from separate PNG files?  You would have one for the frame, one for the cushion, and one for the background.  You would re-color the frame and cushion accordingly then layer them into a single image.

Comment: i guess there is no way other then having two separate images for frame and cushion. otherwise in some cases trying to color frame might cause cushion color changed or vice version. I would try to do the coding based on your ideas. Thanks Colin and Lucas both!

Comment: Sure thing :)  I wish I could give you some working code, but I've never dealt with image manipulation in C# before.

Comment: Performance can be an important thing in your case of image processing. You can try to use unsafe code to speed it up. There was a question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203851/faster-method-to-loop-through-image. Alternatively you could define a set of few available colors and use manually prepared images (containing a part of the image) in different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Detecting parts of the image to be modified**

Detecting objects on images programatically is probably not the simplet thing to do ;). I suppose one of the good solutions to this problem was suggested by ***Collin O'Dell*** in his comment to the question. He suggested to use few images with manually separated parts of the image you want to recolor. Then, you can compose the final image from few different layers.

However, you can also keep the main image with all the objects and manually make some additional images, but only to keep ***masks of the objects*** (i.e. white pixels in places where the object is). You can then easily check which pixels should be recolored. This would allow you to paint directly on one image and avoid compositing.

**Calculating the color**

When you want to recolor the photograph, you probably want to be able to keep the shading effects etc. rather than covering all with the same solid color. 
In order to achieve this, you can use ***HSV*** color space instead of ***RGB***. To use this method you should:

- read pixel's color (in ***RGB***)
- recalculate it to ***HSV***
- change ***Hue*** value of the color to get the desired color shade
- recaluclate modified color back to ***RGB***
- set the new color of the pixel

For more information about ***HSV*** color space you can look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV.